# Images not loading on page change using Link in NextJS

Tags: environment-variables, next.js, strapi

This is hard to explain without uploading my full project likely, but here goes. I think I've narrowed it down to some combination of getInitialProps() and getStaticProps(). When I use next/link to change pages images are not being loaded. If I browse directly to the page images will load fine. Project is fairly simple with only 2 pages, index.js and [slug].js. Here's both:

index.js

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/layout';
import Seo from '../components/seo';
import Hero from '../components/hero';
import Forcast from '../components/forcast';
import { fetchAPI } from '../lib/api';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';

const Home = ({ pages, homepage }) => {
  return (
    <Layout pages={pages}>
      <Seo seo={homepage.seo} />
      <Hero hero={homepage.hero} />
      <Forcast />
      <main className='main-content'>
        <div className='fullwidth-block'>
          <div className='container'>
            <div className='post single'>
              <div className='entry-content'>
                <ReactMarkdown 
                  source={homepage.Content} 
                  escapeHtml={false} 
                  transformImageUri={uri => 
                    uri.startsWith('http') ? uri : `${process.env.REACT_APP_IMAGE_BASE_URL}/${uri}`
                  }
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  // Run API calls in parallel
  const [pages, homepage] = await Promise.all([
    fetchAPI('/pages'),
    fetchAPI('/homepage'),
  ]);

  return {
    props: { pages, homepage },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
}

export default Home;
```

[slug].js

```jsx
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
import Layout from '../components/layout';
import Seo from '../components/seo';
import { fetchAPI } from '../lib/api';

const Page = ({ page, pages }) => {
  const seo = {
    metaTitle: page.Title,
    metaDescription: page.seo.metaDescription,
    shareImage: page.seo.shareImage,
  }

  return (
    <Layout pages={pages}>
      <Seo seo={page.seo} />
      <main className='main-content'>
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='breadcrumb'>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='fullwidth-block'>
          <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
              <div className='content col-md-8'>
                <div className='post single'>
                  <h2 className='entry-title'>{page.Title}</h2>
                  <ReactMarkdown 
                    source={page.Content} 
                    escapeHtml={false} 
                    transformImageUri={uri => 
                      uri.startsWith('http') ? uri : `${process.env.REACT_APP_IMAGE_BASE_URL}${uri}`
                    }
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const pages = await fetchAPI('/pages');
  return {
    paths: pages.map((page) => ({
      params: {
        slug: page.slug,
      },
    })),
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const pages = await fetchAPI(
    `/pages?slug=${params.slug}`
  );
  return {
    props: { page: pages[0], pages },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
}

export default Page;
```

This might also be a Strapi issue though I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you get an error when the images fail loading (check your `Network` tab in dev tools)? Are the images using the expected URL when they fail loading? It might be related to the `transformImageUri` function you are passing to `ReactMarkdown` component.

Comment: I do. I receive a 404 on page reload. It's adding /undefined/ in between the image path  and localhost:3000/ so URLs look like "http://localhost:3000/undefined/uploads/..."

Comment: The `undefined` probably comes from the `REACT_APP_IMAGE_BASE_URL` env var not being available on the browser. How are you setting up your environment variables?

Comment: It's being passed in a .env.development file. It only has one variable in it: ```REACT_APP_IMAGE_BASE_URL=http://localhost:1337```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue happens because the `REACT_APP_IMAGE_BASE_URL` is not exposed to the browser, and only available on the server.

To have it exposed to the browser you'll need to add the [`NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) to it.

```sh
# .env.development

NEXT_PUBLIC_REACT_APP_IMAGE_BASE_URL=http://localhost:1337
```

Then in your code reference it using `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REACT_APP_IMAGE_BASE_URL`.

Comment: if NEXT_PUBLIC_ is required, can I remove REACT_APP_ prefix off the variable? I assumed that was the only requirement.

Comment: Yes, you can remove the `REACT_APP_` prefix, it's not required in Next.js.

Comment: Great! I'll give it a shot in a bit and update the question with an approved answer. Thanks!